# Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: Error: Could not find ID for Fiber "SvgCheck"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a state and depending if it's true or false I show a different svg icon, although I noticed switching between the state caused this error to appear:
Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: Error: Could not find ID for Fiber "SvgCheck",
I have my icons in a public/static/icons, all svg files are here and then I have index.js where I import those icons and then export like

```
import Check from './check.svg'
export {
...
Check,
}
```

Then I am importing them as:

```
import {Check} from "public/static/icons"
```

and I use them as `<Check/>`

to allow me to use it like this I am using svgr plugin in next.config.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
      });
  
      return config;
    }
  };
```

I only started getting this warning recently and never saw it before.

Comment: I started getting this too and we're using create react app.

Comment: I started getting this warning today

Comment: this error seems to be related with react devtools extension, although I am not sure and didn't try to remove it yet

Comment: I have sent a message to the Facebook team responsible for RDT, through the contact link on the extension page.

This started to happen for me after the release of React Developer Tools, Version 4.13.4 Updated May 21, 2021

But will also take a look myself at https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions

Comment: Seems to be related to https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21516

Answer (score 17):

Hi  I'm the author and maintainer of React DevTools.

The error you're asking about is related to the interaction between React DevTools and React Refresh.

These bugs have existed for a while, but recently became more visible because of an intentional change to surface errors earlier ([21426](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21426)) so that bug reports would include the original error and not a downstream error (which is much harder to attribute and fix).

I've been fixing instances of the DevTools+Refresh for the last week or two ([21536](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21536), [21516](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21516), [21523](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/21523)) but I haven't gotten them all yet. Sorry.

If you have a way to reproduce the bug you're seeing, [please tell me about it on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Component%3A%20Developer%20Tools%2CType%3A%20Bug%2CStatus%3A%20Unconfirmed&template=devtools_bug_report.yml&title=%5BDevTools%20Bug%5D%3A%20) (with code and instructions) so that I can hopefully fix it for you. I don't really check Stack Overflow for this sort of thing.

Comment: I think this is pretty much resolved at this point. Probably worth accepting this answer @Alfred

Comment: Agreed. All known instances of this type of bug have now been fixed and we haven't gotten any new reports of them in a few days.

Comment: Universe bless you